# I received notification from firebase but how can i display these messages of notification and transfer it to my mainlayout?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is code of firebase messaging service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("msgBody", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    Intent new_intent = new Intent();
    new_intent.setAction("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
    new_intent.putExtra("msg", bundle);
    sendBroadcast(new_intent);
    Log.d(TAG,"FROM:"+remoteMessage.getFrom());
    //check if the message contains data
    if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
        Log.d(TAG,"Message data:"+remoteMessage.getData());

        //check if the message contains notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message body:"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
    }
}
```

/*
* display notification This is code to display notification This is code to display notification This is code to display notification
* */

```
private void sendNotification(String body) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0/*request code*/,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //set sound notification
    Uri notifictaionSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
             NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new 
             NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notifictaionSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=
    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0/*ID of 
    notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service onMessageReceived() call the method

```
if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Message body:"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendMessageToActivity();

    }
```

and add this as a method

```
private static void sendMessageToActivity(String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("Notification");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In the activity you want to receive

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
        //do what you want with the notification

    }
};
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("Notification"));
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Could u pls edit it from my code?

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent); where context come from?

Comment: im new to android development. Could u be more detailed?

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(int‌​ent); use this

Comment: The error is :"this" can not be referenced from a static context

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this).sendBroadcast(int‌​e‌​nt); use this

Comment: it seems same error but u give me good solution to use broadcast to solve it.Thanks

Comment: Awesome, if it helped please consider marking the answer as accepted by pressing the green tick in the answer